# Array of Vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting a segmentation fault if the value of "no_vertices" is more than 2. The code is as follows

```
vector<int> a[no_vertices];
for(int i=1;i<=no_vertices-1;i++)
{
    int v1,v2;
    cin>>v1>>v2;
    a[v1].push_back(v2);
    a[v2].push_back(v1);
}
```

I am trying to make a bidirectional graph using an adjacency list. So I am trying to use an array of vectors. But I am getting a segmentation fault at the console after entering all the values i.e., right after the for loop ends.

Comment: Where do you get the segfault? Care to provide a little more information?

Comment: What is `pb`? If you mean `push_back` then *say* so.

Comment: Where are the `vector`s?

Comment: @ArneMertz I get the segmentation fault after entering the values of v1 and v2 for no_vertices times.

Comment: Also, what is the input you give the program? Is `v1` and `v2` guaranteed to be between zero and `no_vertices - 1`?

Comment: ‘*My array indices start from 1*’ What?!

Comment: You get the segmentation fault if v1 >= no_vertices or v2 >= no_vertices... as said in other comments the problems appears because of the input values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> a(no_vertices, vector<int>());
for (int i = 0; i < no_vertices; i++)
{
    int v1, v2;
    cin >> v1 >> v2;
    if (v1 < 0 || v1 >= no_vertices || v2 < 0 || v2 >= no_vertices)
    {
        cout << "incorrect value!" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    a[v1].push_back(v2);
    a[v2].push_back(v1);
}
```

Make sure that your v1 and v2 values are in range: `[0, no_vertices - 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Since the input values are used for indexing, they must both be in the range 0 through `no_vertices`-1 for each iteration.

Otherwise you have Undefined Behavior.

It's not a good idea to use input values directly that way. Add logic that **validates** the input values. I.e., that they're in the required range.